# What type of wall do I have? (Mounting pull-up bar to side of house)

Tags: mounting

Before I commit to lining up at Home Depot, I'd like to know what type of wall I have.

I plan on installing this pull-up bar and doing dynamic exercises (swinging muscle-ups) as well standard pull-ups.
https://www.titan.fitness/strength/strength-accessories/pull-up-bars/titan-wall-mounted-pull-up-chin-up-bar/400510.html#

Questions:

1. Fairly sure my wall is not concrete/cement, but can someone confirm this is just typical drywall exterior with easy-to-access wooden studs?  Unfortunately I don't have a stud finder.
2. Do I need to buy anything other than the recommended 3"x3/8" lag bolts, washers, and wall anchors?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody can determine the type of wall you have from that picture.   It could literally be anything, well except drywall.

Comment: you want the bar hanging _outside_ the house?

Comment: Could be stucco. Stucco over concrete or block, use the appropriate anchor. Stucco over wood, going to be hard to find the studs. Tapping with a hammer should give some clues.

Comment: @DMoore Sorry, any suggestions on how to get a better photo?   Yes, hanging outside the house.

Comment: Take several pictures from different distances and parts of the house.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like stucco over chicken wire, where the chicken wire is attached to the studs in the wall on stand-offs, which makes it hard to find the studs because magnetic stud finders will see the chicken wire.

Putting any kind of mechanical stress and strain on that wall will likely result in cracking the stucco, which then lets it leak in the rain and cause rot inside. I would mount a large sheet of 3/4" outdoor plywood to the wall in at least 6 places direct to studs (once you find them), then mount your bar to the plywood, trying to spread the forces out over a larger area.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion at all. Note of caution to OP: mounting the plywood could (most likely _will_) cause fractures in the stucco, allowing water in. Be sure to _thoroughly_ seal with silicone sealant inside the bolt holes, behind the bolt holes through the plywood, under the bolt/washer outside the plywood, and around the top and sides of the plywood (leaving the bottom unsealed to allow any moisture that _does_ get in a place to get out.

Comment: Good points, and also if you drill holes to find the first stud, make sure to seal all of those holes too.